# Homotopy injection between the unit ball in the Euclidean n space and an n-dimensional metric AR

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $D^n$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Given a compact, $n$-dimensional, AR(Absolute Retract) metric space $X$, must it happen that either $X$ embeds in $D^n$ or $D^n$ embeds in $X$?

Thank you

Comment: ?? -- make your ball big enough.

Comment: @Włodzimierz Holsztyński I do not understand your comment, in general $X$ does not embeds in $\mathbf{R}^n$. Could you explain what do you mean?

Comment: My mistake, sorry (I assumed--wrongly--that $\ X\subseteq\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: There are plenty of the requested examples. Karol Borsuk had a paper in dimension $\ 2\ $ with a more advanced goal. The paper was presented during the first topological conference in Prague, during the summer of 1961. And it was published in the conference proceedings.

Comment: @Włodzimierz Holsztyński The paper contains counterexamples? Could you give more details about the paper of Borsuk? Thanks!

Comment: It's been a while ago (I don't have the paper around me available). Disk is treated as any other 2-dim metric compact AR. Borsuk constructed a continuum of 2-dim metric compact ARs such that none of them contains a subset homeomorphic to any open subset of any other. *** *** Later, a still harder example was provided (if my memory serves me well enough) jointly by Bing and Borsuk--they constructed a 3-dim metric compact AR which doesn't contain any subspace homeomorphic to a disk (i.e. $\ \mathbb I^2$).